# I have a problem with login to a site from C# desktop application

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I want to login to the site [bakcell.com/en/login](http://bakcell.com/en/login) and do something with the same session, but when I try this code I get this error:

> The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

Code:

```
HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://bakcell.com/en/login");
HttpWebResponse rs = (HttpWebResponse)wr.GetResponse();
Stream s = rs.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader srt = new StreamReader(s);
receiveData = srt.ReadToEnd();
```

But when I open this URL from any web browser it works normal, so how can I request as a web browser would to get the body specified with this URL?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing your user agent to something standard, like Mozilla/5.0 ?